# Traversing general nodes class, listing all nodes results in a infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I am practicing traversing trees/nodes and i came to the current problem. I want to be able to connect one node to itself. Connect node 1 to node 2. Nodes can be connected to as many nodes as desirable. This is the current class that i wrote and practicing with.

My problem is that i cannot check if i already traversed a past node. What i get is an infinite loop of one -> two -> three -> four -> one -> two ... and so on.

Would be possible to be given a tip to the right direction?

I want nodeN.list_connections() to be able to print all nodes that nodeN connects to.

```
class Node {
private:
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
    std::string data;
public:
    Node()
    {
        printf("Status: Created [%d]\n", this);
    }
    void connect(Node& node)
    {
        nodes.push_back(&node);
        printf("Status: Node [%d] Connected To [%d]\n", this, &node);
    }
    void input_data(std::string str_in)
    {
        data = str_in;
    }
    void list_connections()
    {
        printf("List: Start\n");
        printf("Node[this][%d]: %s\n", this, data.c_str());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
        {
          printf("Node[i=%d][%d]: %s\n", i, nodes[i], nodes[i]->data.c_str());
          if (this != nodes[i])
             nodes[i]->list_connections();
        }
    }
};

void test_list()
{
    Node one;
    one.input_data("ONE");
    Node two;
    two.input_data("TWO");
    Node three;
    three.input_data("THREE");
    Node four;
    four.input_data("FOUR");

    // one -> two <-> three -> four -> one
    // one -> one
    // two -> two

    one.connect(two);
    one.connect(one);
    two.connect(two);
    two.connect(three);
    three.connect(four);
    four.connect(one);
    three.connect(two);

    one.list_connections();
    //two.list_connections();
    //three.list_connections();
    //four.list_connections();
}
```

This is my code above.

My test_list function tests all possible connection scenarios.

EDIT:

The current idea of my nodeOne.list_connections(), is that it will loop through all the nodes connected to nodeOne. Those nodes will also use nodeOther.list_connections() only if the current node is not connected to other node.

EDIT:

All the nodes are connected in some way. When listing the connections it will only list connections from that node down. Listing nodes will not go back to the root/first node.

EDIT:

by using only  one.list_connections(); the output should be

```
 List: Start
 Node[this][7731340]: ONE
 Node[i=0][7731288]: TWO
 Node[i=1][7731340]: ONE
 List: Start
 Node[this][7731288]: TWO
 Node[i=0][7731288]: TWO
 Node[i=1][7731236]: THREE
 List: Start
 Node[this][7731236]: THREE
 Node[i=0][7731184]: FOUR
 Node[i=1][7731288]: TWO
 List: Start
 Node[this][7731184]: FOUR
 Node[i=0][7731340]: ONE
```

Thank you StephanH for pointing it out.

Comment: What about having another attribute in Node being a `boolean`. Once you pass one, `boolean passed=true`, so next time, if it is `true`, it ends.

Comment: If you assume a completly connected graph (every node can be reached from every other node with at least one path) you can simple print out every node in your graph and print out all connected nodes without any recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I do want all nodes to be connected. But then for me to print every node in the graph i would need to carry all the nodes information in every node, or at least in root. i dont want to do that. I want to print all the nodes starting from a certain point down. Listing nodes wont go up to root. So i feel like recursion is the only way for me to access next nodes. Thanks M.K i will try.

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tackle a common place problem (avoid cycles) in graph theory. You may create a simple Path class to track if a node was already/or is currently  printed in the current recursion stack. Therefore, you have to check if the new node is already in the recursion stack. Let's use the standard std::find() applied to an integer vector storing node ids. For readability and easier useage I wrapped it in `bool Path::closeCycle(int nid)`. Since a path could consist at most of |N| elements the Path class could also represented by a n-dimensional `vector<bool>` which would avoid using `std::find()`. This could increase performance, but this perhaps depends on the structure of your graph (long paths+few nodes vs. short paths+hugh amount of nodes vs. something between vs. extrems).

In node.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class Path
{
    std::vector<int> vals;
public:
    Path();
    bool closeCycle(int nid)const;
    void add(int nid);
};

class Node {
private:
    int id;
    std::vector<Node*> nodes;
    std::string data;
public:
    Node(int id) : id(id)
    {
        printf("Status: Created [%d]\n", this);
    }
    void connect(Node& node)
    {
        nodes.push_back(&node);
        printf("Status: Node [%d] Connected To [%d]\n", this, &node);
    }
    void input_data(std::string str_in)
    {
        data = str_in;
    }
    void list_connections(const Path& path = Path());
    inline int getId()const { return id; }
};
```

In node.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void Node::list_connections(const Path& path)
{
    printf("List: Start\n");
    printf("Node[this][%d]: %s\n", this, data.c_str());


    Path npath(path);
    npath.add(id);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!npath.closeCycle(nodes[i]->id))
        {
            printf("Node[i=%d][%d]: %s\n", i, nodes[i], nodes[i]->data.c_str());
            nodes[i]->list_connections(npath);
        }
    }
    printf("List: %s End\n", data.c_str());
}



Path::Path()
{
}

bool Path::closeCycle(int nid) const
{
    return std::find(vals.begin(), vals.end(), nid) != vals.end();
}

void Path::add(int nid)
{
    vals.push_back(nid);
}
```

Your main.cpp

```
void main()
{
    Node one(1);
    one.input_data("ONE");
    Node two(2);
    two.input_data("TWO");
    Node three(3);
    three.input_data("THREE");
    Node four(4);
    four.input_data("FOUR");

    one.connect(two);
    one.connect(one);
    two.connect(two);
    two.connect(three);
    three.connect(four);
    four.connect(one);
    three.connect(two);

    one.list_connections();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    two.list_connections();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    three.list_connections();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    four.list_connections();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I can see the confusion. I apologies. I want the exact result however by using only one command, one.list_connections();

Comment: thank you very much, i guess i was thinking too close mind when tackling the problem. I kept trying to think of adding more and more if statements in list_connections. This sounds like an interesting way of doing this. I will try it and add/change a few things. Thank you very much. I will share my code once im done, playing around with it.

Comment: You're welcome. This problem must be solved since it causes a stackoverflow ;) I am looking forward for your improved version